# GitLab CI: Export variable in before_script build job

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to implement a conditional versioning depending on if the CI script runs for a tagged branch or not.
However the version var is not resolved. Instead it is printed as a string.

The relevant jobs of the GitLab CI script:

```
# build template
.build_base_template: &build_base_template
  image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxxxx/npm:latest
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: LintBuildTest
  script:
    - export CUR_VERSION='$(cat ./version.txt)$BUILD_VERSION_SUFFIX'
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist/

# default build job
build:
  before_script:
    - export BUILD_VERSION_SUFFIX='-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-SNAPSHOT-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA'
  <<: *build_base_template
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
  only:
    variables:
      - $FEATURE_NAME == null

# specific build job for tagged versions
build_tag:
  before_script:
    - export BUILD_VERSION_SUFFIX=''
  <<: *build_base_template
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
```

Comment: My colleague was able to resolve the problem. I would like to provide the solution to everybody: Calling the build_base_template needs to be called first (above the line of `before_script`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in general you can't export variables from child to parent processes.

As workaround you can use text file to write/read variable value. Also maybe it's possible to pass variable via yaml template.

Answer (score 13):

Variables which are exported within **before_script** are visible within **script**.

```
before:
  before_script:
    - export HELLOWELT="hi martin"
  script:
    - echo $HELLOWELT  # prints "hi martin"
```

Comment: But [not in after_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#execution-shell-environment)

Comment: You actually don't need an export in this example because „[Scripts you specify in `before_script` are concatenated with any scripts you specify in the main script. The combined scripts execute together in a single shell.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script)“

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Runner [internal variable expansion mechanism](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-runner-internal-variable-expansion-mechanism)

> Not supported: variables defined inside of custom scripts (for example, export MY_VARIABLE="test").

So, you have 3 (three) [options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#define-a-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file):

1. project/group variables
2. `.gitlab-ci.yml` variables
3. `config.toml` variables